# Render React MUI Button variant based on NavLink isActive state TypeScript MUI React-Router v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to conditionally change mui Button's variant based on Navlink's isActive state but get an error

```
  <Button to="/" component={NavLink} variant={({isActive}:{isActive:any}) => isActive ? 'contained' : 'outlined'}>
    Home
  </Button>
```

ERROR:
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in src/features/navbar/Navbar.tsx:17:50

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning" | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
Type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => "outlined" | "contained"' is not assignable to type '"text" | "outlined" | "contained" | undefined'.
Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<NavLinkProps & RefAttributes>; } & { ...; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
Type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => "outlined" | "contained"' is not assignable to type '"text" | "outlined" | "contained" | undefined'.
Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>>): Element', gave the following error.
Type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => "outlined" | "contained"' is not assignable to type '"text" | "outlined" | "contained" | undefined'.
15 |       }}
16 |     >

> 17 |       <Button to="/" component={NavLink} variant={({isActive}:{isActive:any}) => isActive ? 'contained' : 'outlined'}>
> |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 18 |         Home
> 19 |       
> 20 |

Comment: Only the `NavLink` component's `className`, `style`, and `children` props take a function that is passed an object with an `isActive` property. I don't think there's a way to render the `NavLink` component *as* the button ***and*** set the button variant. You may need to render the `Button` as a child of the `NavLink` so you can access the `isActive` property.

Comment: Can I somehow extend this functionality to make it compatible with MUI Button's props as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer. Instead of passing NavLink as component to MUI Button, I wrapped the Button in a Navlink and rendered it conditionally there:
<NavLink to='/' end style={{textDecoration:'none'}}>
{({ isActive }) => (
<Button sx={{textDecoration: 'none'}} variant={isActive ? 'contained' : 'outlined'}>
Home

)}

ps.: textDecoration: 'none' is required to remove underline from the NavLink

Comment: Yup, this was what I was trying to suggest. Cheers.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for all these questions, rather than wrapping everything or creating custom components, simply access the isActive and isPending props in the children. It's in the interface. Thank you for this answer.


`export interface NavLinkProps extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style" | "children"> {
    children?: React.ReactNode | ((props: {
        isActive: boolean;
        isPending: boolean;
    }) => React.ReactNode);`